# How do I remove text in BETWEEN patterns in regex javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some HTML tags that I need to parse out for saving to database.

```
<div class="hello" id="one"> </div> 
<span id="123123" > </span>
```

All I want remaining is

```
<div> </div>
<span> </span>
```

How can i do this with regex?

I know that I can do it in HTML-- but the point isn't to re-display it without classes, but to save it to a database bare-bones.

ALso hoping to avoid lookbacks

Thanks

Comment: `<div className="hello"` but `className` is not `class`. `className` is used in JS, not HTML.

Comment: Thanks will fix. Do you have ideas?

Comment: Have you tried writing some regular expressions? Groups of capture groups should do the trick. Also, what is _lookbacks_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DOMParser` instead, and iterate over the attributes of each element, and remove each attribute:

```js
const htmlText = `<div className="hello" id="one"> </div> 
<span id="123123" > </span>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlText, 'text/html');
doc.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((elm) => {
  [...elm.attributes].forEach(({ name }) => {
    elm.removeAttribute(name);
  });
});
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```